# Disabled EnableLUA in RegEdit, cant run as administrator

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I disabled `EnableLUA` in `Dator\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`, this disabled the "credential screen" for running as admin. Stupid thing tho is that I don't become admin at all. So.... this went south for me.

The computer is using MakeMeAdmin (out of my control, I'm just local admin that messed up).

Is there a way maby in PS or something to run a command and force the "credential screen" again so I can re-enable?

*Clarification*: I can't do ANYTHING that requires being admin since I can't enter credentials. That includes running the reg backup I made before I changed it.

Comment: This can only be resolved with an actual Administrator account.  Have another Administrator on the system, enable the built-in Administrator account which is disabled and does not use the UAC, to restore the system to a functional state.

Comment: Im on the go. But could I sudo in Ubuntu terminal? I've installed it.

Comment: What command are you thinking about running exactly?  Of course it does not matter since WSL wouldn't have access to the Windows registry anyways.

Comment: It was a no go. "Ubuntu" needed admin

Comment: I meant starting regedit.exe from ubuntu terminal

Comment: No, that's really NOT how it works. Please read an understand the very first comment. You can't do it from WSL, otherwise that would be a HUGE security hole.

Comment: @DannyThunder - What were you expecting by running the registry editor from WSL? A process, by default, unless explicitly elevated by the user, will run at the lowest permissions the user or process has, which means WSL, which has unevaluated user permissions on your system, would run the registry editor at the same permissions as the user running the registry editor itself.  There is a way to take ownership of the registry key, I just think it's a mistake and a red hearing, to the actual solution you are looking for.

Comment: I was by chance. I don't use win that much, I use macos and linux. Thanks for all info guys.